# Calculate total hours between cell like 9-5?

Tags: excel-formula, sum

I'm looking to create a shift schedule sheet for my team. This is what I've got so far:
[image]

How do I calculate the total hours for the 7 days in between those times?

Thanks

Comment: In that format, the formulas will be pretty ugly. I'd suggest putting start and end time in separate cells.

Comment: Have done now, please see here https://i.imgur.com/V1bzaYIg.png - what would the formula be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about splitting starting time and end time in two columns such as:

```
|   Monday  |  Tuesday  | ...
| 9am | 5pm | 9am | 5pm | ...
```

Then if you do an arithmetic operation, you'll have a result in days. So simply multiply by 24:

```
 1 |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
 2 |   Monday  |  Tuesday  | ... |
 3 | 9am | 5pm | 9am | 5pm | ... | =24*( (B3-A3) + (D3-C3) ...)
```

Tested in Excel 2013:

### [image: Testing]

Provided that A3, B3, C3... are times. Formatting is up to you obviously.

Comment: Because 1 day has 24h and you most likely want the result in hours, not in days

Comment: Can you make this available as a download please.

Comment: If this works for you, feel free to accept my answer. As for the upload, I just deleted the file :( but the screenshot shows everything you need. The `L2` cell is similar to `L3` cell, just to show you that it works. As for the time formatting, I used `[$-409]h:mm AM/PM;@` (Locale English-US, format `1:30 PM`)

Comment: I am using Google Sheets. Please make it as a download and I will gladly put it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Could you then share a sheet? I'll put the formula on it (as my file is already deleted, I need to redo it)